# How can I create routes between two separate LANs on the internet over an OpenVPN tunnel?

Tags: routing, openvpn, tunnel, openwrt

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8MXX.png)

I have separate router/OpenVPN appliances at two different sites. The appliances are actually TP Link routers running OpenWRT 12.09, r36088. I would like clients behind these two routers to be able to connect to one another.

One router is configured as an OpenVPN server 192.168.10.1 in front of 192.168.10.0/24, the other as an OpenVPN client 10.1.1.1 in front of 10.1.1.0/24.

As of now, there is a kind of tunnel between the two. The OpenVPN client can connect to all hosts on 10.1.1.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24. I was able to get the OpenVPN server to connect to the client on its VPN interface, but that's it. **I also can't connect from hosts behind the OpenVPN client to hosts behind the OpenVPN server--this is really my ultimate goal.**

- The server is actually in the DMZ of a comcast small business modem/router (lan IP 192.168.1.1) with all traffic forwarded to it. The server is given 192.168.1.2 by the comcast router, and is 192.168.10.1 on its own LAN side.

SERVER

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0.2  proto static 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
10.8.0.6 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0.2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.10.0/24 dev br-lan  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.1 

# ping 10.8.0.6 -c 2
PING 10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.8.0.6: seq=0 ttl=64 time=48.579 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.6: seq=1 ttl=64 time=236.587 ms

--- 10.8.0.6 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 48.579/142.583/236.587 ms

# ping 10.1.1.1 -c 2
PING 10.1.1.1 (10.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
--- 10.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

## A ROUTE I THINK I MAY NEED TO ADD
# ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.6
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
```

CLIENT

```
# ip route show
default via $PUBLIC_IP dev eth0.2  proto static 
10.1.1.0/24 dev br-lan  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.1 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
$PUBLIC_IP_RANGE dev eth0.2  proto kernel  scope link  src $PUBLIC_IP
192.168.10.0/24 dev tun0  scope link 

# ping 192.168.10.25
PING 192.168.10.25 (192.168.10.25): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.10.25: seq=0 ttl=63 time=294.408 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.25: seq=1 ttl=63 time=21.798 ms

--- 192.168.10.25 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 21.798/158.103/294.408 ms
```

HOST BEHIND CLIENT

```
$ ping 192.168.10.25
PING 192.168.10.25 (192.168.10.25) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.1.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 10.1.1.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable

--- 192.168.10.25 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 999ms

$ traceroute 192.168.10.25
traceroute to 192.168.10.25 (192.168.10.25), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  OpenWrt.lan (10.1.1.1)  0.225 ms  0.230 ms  0.274 ms
 2  OpenWrt.lan (10.1.1.1)  0.350 ms  0.417 ms  0.475 ms
```

What I want to do is kind of covered under this example from the OpenVPN docs](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#examples) find on the page "# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client".

The docs there recommend making alterations to an openvpn server.conf, but for some reason I can't seem to figure out where the final should be or how to load it.

Most of what I know about OpenVPN is written down on this page or on the OpenWRT OpenVPN Setup For Beginners. I guess OpenWRT uses some kind of proprietary configuration management tool uci, so that hid some of the initial openvpn configuration from me.

wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/vpn.openvpn

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your setup is unclear.

The way I understand your setup is this:

- You have a 192.168.10.0/24 subnet that is connected to the br-lan interface of box A.
- Box A is your OpenVPN server.
- Box A's VPN IP is 10.8.0.5.
- Box B is your OpenVPN client.
- Box B's VPN IP is 10.8.0.2.
- There is a 10.1.1.0/24 subnet connected to the br-lan interface of box B.

There are two IPs whose function is unclear: 10.8.0.1 and 10.8.0.6. What interfaces on which boxes are they assigned to and what should their function be?

Discounting the mystery of 10.8.0.{1,6}, what appears to be missing is a route on box A to the subnet behind box B:

```
ip ro add 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
```